# CFMAIL : Emails not working for some emails

Tags: email, coldfusion

I am using cfmail tag. I am able to send emails however its not totally working. One problem is that for some it go to the junk folder. And secondly, for some emails it doesn't even reach the destination.

I am working for a university and they have their gmail portal with their own email extension. for example @universityname.ca but its actually a gmail account. I am trying to send email to this and it doesn't even reach the destination.

I assume these emails are being filtered out as spams and blocked before reaching, what settings do I need so they don't go to junk and they are not filtered out as spam.

snippet:

```
<cfmail to="my.email@universityname.ca" from="sender@gmail.com" subject="Example email">
  Your Email Message!!
</cfmail>
```

Also I am not admin, thus I don't have access to mail settings.

Comment: you might want to check out google's postmaster tools https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6227174

Comment: Here is some light reading for you.  http://www.trunkful.com/index.cfm/2010/5/27/How-to-CFMAIL-Properly-and-Keep-the-SPAM-in-the-Can

Answer (score 1):

Some email providers have very strict settings that make it nearly impossible to spoof a 'FROM' address with `cfmail`.

On top of that, sometimes you have to [allow "less secure" apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) to access your gmail account if you want ColdFusion to be able to send automated messages. That may be stopping you before you even get started.

Here is an example of what I do on my server. By specifying a port, server, username, and password of the true 'FROM' address, I never run into problems, and instead of spoofing an email address outright, I just mask it like so, then change the `replyto` attribute to something appropriate.

```
<cfmail 
to="me@me.com" 
from="Custom Name Here <XXX@x.com>" 
subject="Website Contact" 
type="html"  
server="smtp.gmail.com" 
port="587" 
username="XXX@x.com" 
password="ZZZ"  
usetls="true">

Content

</cfmail>
```